# Capture sub-string at different positions from command's output

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I have a requirement, where I have to capture a string from a command's output and store it for further processing. Problem is that the command's output may change sometimes and hence this leads to erroneous results.

---

Requested dataset looks like

```
application_1532934978357_3376 app_name job_type user any_name_2 RUNNING 
UNDEFINED 10% hostname
application_1532934978357_3375 app_name job_type user any_name_2 RUNNING 
UNDEFINED 10% hostname
application_1532934978357_3374 app_name job_type user any_name_2 RUNNING 
UNDEFINED 10% hostname
application_1532934978357_249069 some_information_etc job_type any_name_2 
RUNNING UNDEFINED 95% hostname
application_1532934978357_239728 app_name job_type any_name_2 RUNNING 
UNDEFINED 10% hostname
application_1532934978357_89483 some_info job_type user any_name RUNNING 
UNDEFINED 10% hostname
application_1532934978357_248180 with prog_vrsn as
(se...select cast(Stage-27) job_type user any_name RUNNING UNDEFINED 36.1% 
hostname
application_15329349783879_657880 select cast
value ..(stage35) with table
where value=5; job_type user any_name RUNNING UNDEFINED 10% hostname
```

and I use:

```
cat in | grep "RUNNING" | grep "any_name" | awk '{print $1}'
```

which generates output as

```
application_1532934978357_89483 
(se...select cast(Stage-27)
where
```

While I want to produce output as :

```
application_1532934978357_89483 
application_1532934978357_248180 
application_15329349783879_657880
```

Comment: It is always recommended to wrap your samples in CODE TAGS `{}` button please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a GNU awk script that only captures the `application_XXXX` associated to the word `any_name`:

```
awk -v RS='[ \n]' '/application_[0-9_]+/{a=$0}/\<any_name\>/{print a}' file
```

It relies on the record separator `RS` that is set to capture each word. The `application_XXXX` string is stored in the variable `a` and printed when the word `any_name` is found.

Comment: thanks for editing and attempting towards the solution.

Comment: Though when I tried above it just gives me/prints id_tag value. To add some more information . app_id -> actually looks like : app_xxxx_xxx (x=integers). And id_tag looks like : some.string_srting.string.  Lines are separated by "\n" and fields are separated by spaces. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @cod_enthu Please update your question with an  example that has the use cases you're describing. Please also give the expected output. Unfortunately I can't help more with the given example.

Comment: I have now updated the dataset and expected output in question.

Comment: do you need more information regarding problem statement, let me know.

Comment: @Cod_enthu Why is `application_1532934978357_239728` not listed in your expected output since that line contain `any_name`?

Comment: sorry it was a typo, I have updated input to remove redundant any_name string.

Comment: Great, thanks. What if I want to print 'a' , for more than one word (any_name), for ex: capture 'a' if any_name or any_name_2 appears, using above shared solution?

Comment: @Cod_enthu If so, just change the 2nd condition to `/\<any_name\>|\<any_other_word\>/` or `/\<any_name_?2?\>/`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one more grep in your command:

`command's output | grep "status_run" | grep -e "id_tag1" -e "id_tag2" | grep "app_id" | awk '{print $1}'`

OR

`awk '(/status_run/) && (/app_id*/) && (/id_tag[12]/) {print $1;}' filename`

This will only print all the app_id with id_tag1 and id_tag2 and which has "status_run" in them.

---

Solution after updating your question:

`cat filename | grep "RUNNING" | grep "any_name" | grep "application*" | awk '{print $1}'`

If you want to print all the application Ids, then use the below command:

`awk '/application*/{print $1}' filename`

Comment: All of the code should be refactored into a single Awk script though.

Comment: @tripleee I think @oliv has answered it. He is missing the `status_run` part.

Comment: `You just need to add one more grep` - that's funny :-). `awk '/foo/' file | awk '{print $1}'` = `awk '/foo/{print $1}' file`.

Comment: Also awk uses real regexps not glob patterns; `/app_id*/` matches any of `app_i app_id app_idd app_idddddddd` etc. You may have meant `/app_id.*/` (`app_id` followed by any characters) but you don't need the `.*` because awk matches are unanchored by default.

Comment: @Ashutosh updated command/solution also will miss application IDs : 

    


    application_1532934978357_248180 
    application_15329349783879_657880

Comment: @Cod_enthu Not sure what you are trying to say. I think you want to print all the application ID not matter what, right?

Comment: there is an application_ID associated with each any_name string, their order/placement differs as I have shown in the input and hence if I am to follow the command I have or what you wrote it will print the kind of output I am getting, instead I want the one i listed in as desired. You can simply run your command against dataset I have put and you will see what I mean. Let me know if you have further question understanding the problem statement.

Comment: Have you tried this command: `awk '/application*/{print $1}' filename`?

Comment: That will fetch all application ids, while I want application ids corresponding to specific any_name string. (any_name string can be different ).

Comment: But I produced the exact output as you required. You can try it your self.

Comment: Please see updated question, hope it clarifies the requirement further. Looking to fetch applicaiton IDs against specific any_name, not all application ID's from the file.